# How would I scale an animated scene?

Tags: animation, units

I am making a new animation for a company, based on their previous version that I have received. The previous version is at some arbitrary scale, but since I am updating and adding geometry (new product) it would be nice to have the scene to scale. (1 blender unit = 1m) Just resizing everything is not enough, as some objects pop back in place & size due to animation keyframes.

Is there an easy way to scale the whole scene, including camera animation, textures etc. so that I can work on it "to scale"?

Answer (score 3):

Add an *Empty* and patent all the objects to it. Then scale the empty.
[image]
[image]